# odd output for an Account app in java

Tags: java, jgrasp

so i have an assignment for a java programming II class that requires me to create a class called Account that is to do the following:

> Design a class named Account that contains:
>
> Data Members:
>
> A private data filed of type int named id for the account;
>
> A private data field of type double named balance for the account;
>
> A private data field of type double named annualInterestRate that
>   stores the current interest rate (assume all accounts have the same
>   interest rate);
>
> A private data field of type Date named dateCreated that stores the
>   date when the account was created;
>
> Methods A no-arg constructor that creates a default account and sets
>   the following data members to 0 (zero):   id, balance, and
>   annualInterestRate;
>
> A constructor that creates an account with the specified id and
>   initial balance;
>
> The accessor and mutator methods for id, balance and
>   annualInterestRate;
>
> The accessor method for dateCreated
>
> A method named getMonthlyInterestRate( ) that returns the monthly
>   interest rate;
>
> A method named getMonthlyInterest( ) that returns the monthly
>   interest;
>
> A method named withdraw that withdraws a specified amount from the
>   account;
>
> A method named deposit that deposits a specified amount into the
>   account.
>
> Write a test program that creates an Account object with an account ID
>   of 1122, a balance of $20,000, and an annual interest rate of 4.5%.
>   Use the withdraw method to withdraw $2,500, use the deposit method to
>   deposit $3,000, and print the balance, the monthly interest, and the
>   date when this account was created.

the tester app has been given to us by the professor, which i will link down below. all that is required is to create the Account class, which i have. everything compiles correctly, however when i run the tester app the output i get is very odd :

```
----jGRASP exec: java AccountTest


Current account values: 
Account@208e2fb5

Current account values: 
Account@208e2fb5

Current account values: 
Account@208e2fb5
```

im at a loss right now, i have no idea what to do or where to go from here.

Tester App:

```
public class AccountTest
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {

      Account a = new Account(1122, 20000.00);
      a.setAnnualInterestRate(4.5);

     System.out.println("\nCurrent account values: \n" + a);

      a.withdraw(2500.00);
      System.out.println("\nCurrent account values: \n" + a);

      a.deposit(3000.00);
      System.out.println("\nCurrent account values: \n" + a);
   }
}
```

Account Class i created:

```
import java.util.Date;
public class Account
{
   private int id;
   private double balance;
   private double annualInterestRate;
   private Date date = new Date();


   Account()
   {
      id = 0;
      balance = 0.0;
      annualInterestRate = 0.0;
   }

   Account(int newId, double bal)
   {
      id = newId;
      balance = bal;
   }

   public void setId(int newId)
   {
      id = newId;
   }

   public void setBalance( double bal)
   {
      balance = bal;
   }

   public void setAnnualInterestRate(double annualRate)
   {
      annualInterestRate = annualRate;
   }       

   public int getId()
   { 
      return id;
   }

   public double getBalance()
   {
      return balance;
   }

   public double getAnnualInterestRate()
   {
      return annualInterestRate;
   }         


   /*public void setDate(Date n)
   {
      dateCreated = n;
   }*/

   public java.util.Date getDate()
   {
      return date;
   }   

   double getMonthlyInterestRate()
   {
      return annualInterestRate/12;
   }

   double withdraw(double amount)
   {
      return balance -= amount;
   }

   double deposit(double amount)
   {
      return balance += amount;
   }    
}
```

apologies in advanced for my formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing string representation of object.You cant expect for java to know on its own what you want to have printed.

I recommend you override toString method in your object **Account** that prints detail/values of fields of current object.

You can check how to override toString method [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overriding-tostring-method-in-java/)

Bud if you just want to print one value 
for instance

```
  System.out.println("\nCurrent account interest rate :" +  a.getAnnualInterestRate());
```

**Update to your comment.-:**

```
 @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Here is detail of my object name : %s value : %d",stringValue,doubleValue);
    }
```

Comment: i read the article and followed its formatting, but now im getting the following error:

 no suitable method found for format(double)
       return String.format(id + balance);
                    ^
    method String.format(Locale,String,Object...) is not applicable
      (actual argument double cannot be converted to Locale by method invocation conversion)
    method String.format(String,Object...) is not applicable
      (actual argument double cannot be converted to String by method invocation conversion)

im reaching character limit so i will paste the code in another comment

Comment: heres the code i typed in right after my Account object:

    `@Override
    public String toString() 
    {
       return String.format(id + balance);
    }`

Comment: @user3882666 You really have to check documentation/basics of java language.Check String's format() method documentation.String.format("number is %d",balance); //Where %d is placeholder for actual value,and balance is for instance supplyer/parameter for that value.You dont even have to use format method if you dont know how to use it yet.Use plain old string concatenation.

Comment: got it sorted out, i talked to the professor and he told me that i needed to fill in the information in the tester app to display the items required, which were balance, monthly interest rate, and date account was created. thank you so much for you help though i appreciate it